# How to have a safe admin handling with reactjs and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, admin

I would like to add functionalities depending on whether or not the user logged in is the administrator but I don't really know which condition (for conditional rendering with delete buttons etc) I should use to check if the user is the admin or not. Is it safe to do it based on the id of the user ? In the first place, I thought about testing the user in every component I want him to have functionalities, with a state called "user" using recoiljs to get access to the user in the whole app but I'm afraid people could change the state with the react tool extension and then pretend they are the admin and so delete articles and stuff... What's the best way to test if a user is the admin or not using firebase authentification in a react project ?

Answer (score 0):

It's never safe for client code to assume admin responsibilities without absolute enforcement from your backend.  It's unsafe because client code can be compromised and might not work the way you expect.  And it's running on a device that the user controls fully.

Client code can check some indicator to see if the user is admin (in whatever way you find suitable), but the final check needs to happen on your backend, either through security rules (if you're using Firebase products like Realtime Database, Firestore, or Cloud Storage), or in code running on a secure backend, including products like Cloud Functions.